# foreach() returns only last item with json_decode()

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Trying to return Google Fonts **families** from a decoded JSON with a foreach() loop,
but I'm only getting **the last family** and not all of them.

I have been struggling, googling, tried everything I know/found, no result !
This is the code, I'm using it inside WordPress.

```
<?php
/**
 * Get Google Fonts.
 */
public function get_google_fonts() {
    $google_api   = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=MY-API-KEY';
    $font_content = wp_remote_get( $google_api, array( 'sslverify' => false ) );
    $content      = json_decode( $font_content['body'], true );

    $items = $content['items']; // I've tried (array) $content['items'];

    // I've tried $i = 0;

    // I've tried $families = array();

    foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) {
        $families = $value['family'];
        BugFu::log( $families, false ); // Correct returning all families.

        // I've tried $i++;
    }
    return array( $families ); // OR return $families; Returning last family.
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: include the JSON response also so that people will know the structure.

Comment: you have to take your variable as an array what you are doing is you are logging output in the foreach loop and overwritting the variable over and over try function array_push($families,$value['family']);

Comment: @AbdulQuadirDewaswala many thanks for pointing this out, and for the array_push() approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overriding the `$families` variable each time you loop :

```php
$families = $value['family'];
```

In order to add an element to an array, you need to do like that :

```php
$families[] = $value['family'];
```

This way, each time you'll loop, `$value['family']` will be added to your `$families` array.

**Edit**

It might also be good to initialise the `$families` variable as an empty array before the `foreach` loop. Because if you have no value in your json, the function will return `null`.

```php
$families = [];
foreach ($items as $key => $value) { ... }

return $families;
```

Comment: instead use array_push($families,$value['family']);

Comment: `$families[] = ...;` seems enough for me ;)

Comment: yes it is enough but some how gives some weird  output in some server

Comment: Do you have an example ? You triggered my interest :D

Comment: try on nginx server

Comment: I use Nginx servers every day, I never had "weird output" as you said :/

Comment: Nginx is not a PHP server though

Comment: will i got one time might be some other reason

Comment: I was so close, and didn't pay attention for the overriding effect in the loop. Thank you both, very much, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` each time it output the `$families`.

But return only return the last `$families`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning the fonts outside foreachloop when all the families have been looped and $families gets to last value therefore only last value is returned